# Add Delay to "Momentary to Toggle Button" Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, analog, button

I have a simple circuit to take a momentary tactile button and make it toggle a power signal on and off. Unfortunately I was now asked to add a delay to the button. So you have to hold it for a second before it operates the circuit.

I am at a loss for any simple passive way to do it. I looked at a simple RC delay, but was unable to make anything work with a time-frame in the seconds without ending up with unrealistic values.

Anyone have any simple ideas that do not involve adding a micro controller?

I'm fine with an RC decay type of timer etc. that does not reset instantly, I am also fine if anyone has an application specific PMIC that does something like this. I just would like to avoid another code base and toolchain.
[image]

Comment: So. You have to hold it for a second or two to turn ON the device. And you have to hold it again for a second or two to turn OFF the device. And if you let up early, then re-pressing it must start the time all over again (it must reset its timing instantly, if released early.) And it must reliably come up in one or the other state when power is gradually applied over some unspecified time. Is that about it? And a sot-23-6 MCU is not okay because it is just another toolchain to support. Yes?

Comment: Good question, it does not need to reset the "timer" instantly, like an RC decay would be fine. My next best option is to hook the button to an RC circuit driving an analog switch connected to PB1/2... I'm trying for a more passive solution then that. Because that is starting to get crazy complex for a power button.

Comment: Yea, no uC due to software load and toolchain etc.

Comment: And buying someone else's sot-23-6 isn't okay because then you've added a boutique part. Which is also bad, yes? (Just trying to work out all the boundaries here.)

Comment: Is [LTC2953](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2953f.pdf) too big and expensive and boutique?

Comment: I didn't mean for this to be a shopping question, but that is a good start. I think that would work, other then a fab premium for sub 0.5mm pitch. I'm going to search for similar chips also. I guess I never knew there were PMIC chips with push button inputs. Thanks!

Comment: Another option you could consider is buying them from someone who has the toolchain and tools, would program them professionally for you and ship qtys you need, as you need, where you need, when you need; and provide the software in case a truck hits them. A sot-23-6 PIC10F200 is one approach. If you want fancy brownout features and some other goodies (like an analog comparator), you could go to the PIC10F(L)320/322 device.  Those chips in any qty is ... cheap. Like 35 cents or something. And they aren't nearly as boutique.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a state diagram that approximates what I imagine you want:

[image]

It's robust, I think.

But as you can see, it's not going to be just a few discrete parts. A reliable timer on the order of seconds can be built with one mosfet and one BJT and a capacitor and a few resistors. The mosfet would be needed because BJTs make terrible multi-second timers as their base current requirements are a pain. But then you also need, probably, another two or three BJTs and a couple more capacitors, I think. So not discrete.

So the MCU idea has already been floated. You could hire someone to supply you with programmed parts (or the manufacturer can do that) and the software and take care of all the toolchain and pre-programming issues and provide you with software backup in case something happens to them. That means setting up a relationship, etc. So.. it's probably off the table, too.

I've already mentioned the ... well yes, boutique and largish and over-featured ... [LTC2953](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2953f.pdf). Just googled it up, actually. Never used one. But looks right in terms of features. I'm sure there are other companies making similar devices now with good specs.

Your "using logic" approach makes me think of a couple of D flops, a 74121 or 555 (used as a one-shot), and an xnor gate. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTNV1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some details are left out of the above. For example, I didn't provide the R and C values required by the 74121. I didn't deal with any proper resetting of the D flops. There's probably conditions that aren't robust. But it gets an idea across.

When the PB is pressed down (the A inputs are falling edge triggers), the 74121 triggers and Q goes HI. That edge causes the left D flop to capture a copy of the EN output. When the 74121 times out, /Q goes HI and that edge causes the right D flop to either take the inverse of the copied EN state or else just the same EN state as before... depending upon the state of the PB when the time-out occurs. If the PB has been released early then its input to the XNOR will be 1 and this will mean that the left D flop will just be copied back to the right D flop. But if the PB is still held down at this time, then its input to the XNOR will be 0 and this will mean that the copied EN state in the left D flop will be inverted and then latched to the right D flop.

Something like that.

---

What you really want is to go do the extra tool chain/MCU stuff. It will cost almost nothing, takes very little programming time to achieve, and you'll be off and running with a nice SOT-23-6 MCU that costs nothing much, takes up no space, and is probably more reliable.